# rails3 jquery autocomplete how to get the id and full name while typing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

1 - how can i get the id based on the first or last name selected?

2 - I was able to have it work for first name or last name, but i want to be able to have a full name (based on first or last name) when i start typing. For example when i type *ev* be able to see Evelin mars, Steve bach, Matt Evans, ....
I have a full name function in my person.rb model.
Is it possible?

***view***

`<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'person_ids[]', '', autocomplete_person_last_name_segments_path, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true, :id_element => '#some_element', :placeholder => "type a name" %>`

***controller***

```
class SegmentsController < ApplicationController    

   autocomplete :person, :last_name   

   ...
```

***route.rb***

```
resources :segments do
   get :autocomplete_person_last_name, :on => :collection
end
```

***person.rb***

```
def full_name
   "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

**UPDATE**

I were able to show the full name by adding `:extra_data => [:first_name], :display_value => :full_name` to the controller and it becomes

***controller***

```
class SegmentsController < ApplicationController    

   autocomplete :person, :last_name, :extra_data => [:first_name], :display_value => :full_name   

   ...
```

But how do i get the id?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your AJAX response, you should see that by default, the id is also returned.
I believe that you actually want to use this id. This is what you can do in your view, using `:ide_element => #Your_model_id"`  :

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'some_label', '', your_autocomplete_path, :id_element => '#yourmodel_id', class: "form-control" %>

<%= f.hidden_field :yourmodel_id, :value => nil %>
```

You can have a look at the github page of the gem, there is a paragraph dealing with this.